# Concatenar String em C sem uso de função strcat()

Tags: c

preciso de uma ajuda, precisava resolver este exercicio de linguagem de programação, seria concatenar uma string, no caso STRING_B na STIRNG_A, sem uso de função pronta, por metodo de ponteiros.

exemplo:

```
ENTRADAS >> "CASA " - "BAHIA"

SAIDA >> CASA BAHIA
```

segue o codigo...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
/*escreva uma funcao em c que recebe a referencia de duas strings e concatena
a segunda na primeira sem usar funcao strcat()*/

void ptr(char *string_a, char *string_b)
{
    int i;
    do{
        string_a++;
    }while(*string_a!='\0');
    do{
        string_a=*string_b;
        string_b++; 
    }while(*string_b!='\0');
}
int main (void)
{
    char string_a[250];
    char string_b[250];
    puts(" -- DIGITE UMA PALAVRA -- ");
    gets(string_a);
    puts(" -- DIGITE UMA PALAVRA -- ");
    gets(string_b);
    ptr(string_a,string_b);
    puts(string_a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem o porque usar o `do_while` e depois incrementar, se o for foi feito para isso, seu código está um pouco confuso para mim, fiz de uma maneira um pouco mais simples:

```
char* ptr(char *string_a, char *string_b)
{
    int i;
   for(i=0; string_a[i]!='\0'; ++i); //Percorre toda a string_a, para saber o tamanho da mesma
   for(int j=0; string_b[j]!='\0'; ++j, ++i) //Percorre toda a string_b, para concatena-la
   {
      string_a[i]=string_b[j];
   }
    string_a[i]='\0';
    return string_a;
}
int main (void)
{
    char string_a[250];
    char string_b[250];
    puts(" -- DIGITE UMA PALAVRA -- ");
    gets(string_a);
    puts(" -- DIGITE UMA PALAVRA -- ");
    gets(string_b);
    puts(ptr(string_a,string_b));
    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/G7pXTU).

**Com while:**

```
char* ptr(char *string_a, char *string_b)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(string_a[i]!='\0') { ++i; }
    while(string_b[j]!='\0') 
    {
        string_a[i]=string_b[j];
        j++; i++;
    }
    string_a[i]='\0';
    return string_a;
}
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/XHWtUC).

Comment: Error] 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode; apresentou este erro!

Comment: @AGenaro Não sei o porque do erro, mas sendo assim faça com while mesmo, editei minha resposta.

Comment: @Francisso Agora deu certo ! Obrigado. so no sue codigo que mandou por ultimo faltou Ponto e virgula depois do '++i'